# programado de subida de archivos a mi hosting

Tags: javascript

tengo un formulario, el cual necesita un archivo para subirse correctamente a mi web, es de tipo archivo o file.
¿cómo hago con javascript para presionar ese boton sin darle click cuando cargue la pagina?

he usado jquery en el input con el evento onload pero sin exito

```
<div>
    <input id="loadFile" type="file" name="archivo" style="color: transparent; width: 120px;">
</div>



 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("loadFile").click();
  });
</script>
```

y

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById("loadFile").click();
    };

  </script>
```

Comment: Juan creo que no se puede abrir el cuadro de diálogo de seleccionar archivos sin ninguna acción por parte del usuario. Se puede incluso poner una función `onclick` en el `input` y lanzarla, pero ni siquiera así se abre el cuadro de diálogo sin que el usuario pulse sobre él, imagino que será por motivos de seguridad. De todos modos, puede que algún genio busque la forma de hacerlo... toca esperar.

Comment: Efectivamente debido a motivos de seguridad es necesaria un acción válida (click, keypress) por parte del usuario. Ejemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/UQfaZ/1/